# Curve fit an exponential decay function in Python using given data points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

With the `curve_fit` function in SciPy I'm able to determine the coefficients that represent the curve shown in the plot below.

```
def func2(t, tau):
    return np.exp(-t / tau)

t2 = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
y2 = func2(t2, 1.2)

y2_noise = 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=t2.size)
y2_curve_noise = y2 + y2_noise

popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(func2, t2, y2_curve_noise)

tau2, = popt2
y2_fit = func2(t2, tau2)
```

[image: example2]

I would like to use a similar function to represent some data points. However, I'm unable to use this approach to fit the data points as shown below.

```
def func4(t, a, tau, c):
    return a * np.exp(-t / tau) + c

t4 = np.array([15445.1, 15445.6, 15446.1, 15446.6, 15447.1, 15447.6, 15448.1,
               15448.6, 15449.1, 15449.6, 15450.1, 15450.6, 15451.1, 15451.6,
               15452.1, 15452.6, 15453.1, 15453.6, 15454.1, 15454.6, 15455.1,
               15455.6, 15456.1, 15456.6, 15457.1, 15457.6, 15458.1, 15458.6,
               15459.1, 15459.6, 15460.1, 15460.6, 15461.1, 15461.6, 15462.1,
               15462.6, 15463.1, 15463.6, 15464.1, 15464.6, 15465.1, 15465.6,
               15466.1, 15466.6, 15467.1, 15467.6, 15468.1, 15468.6, 15469.1,
               15469.6, 15470.1, 15470.6, 15471.1, 15471.6, 15472.1, 15472.6,
               15473.1, 15473.6, 15474.1])

y4 = np.array([4.129, 4.125, 4.123, 4.121, 4.119, 4.118, 4.116, 4.115, 4.114,
               4.113, 4.112, 4.11, 4.11, 4.109, 4.108, 4.108, 4.106, 4.105,
               4.105, 4.104, 4.103, 4.102, 4.102, 4.101, 4.1, 4.1, 4.099,
               4.098, 4.098, 4.097, 4.097, 4.096, 4.095, 4.095, 4.094, 4.094,
               4.093, 4.092, 4.092, 4.091, 4.091, 4.09, 4.09, 4.089, 4.089,
               4.088, 4.088, 4.087, 4.087, 4.086, 4.086, 4.085, 4.085, 4.084,
               4.084, 4.084, 4.083, 4.083, 4.082])

popt4, pcov4 = curve_fit(func4, t4, y4, p0=(4.129, 1.2, 4.082))

a4, tau4, c4 = popt4
y4_fit = func4(t4, a4, tau4, c4)
```

[image: example4]

How can I apply the `curve_fit` in SciPy to fit the data points? Or is there a different curve fitting method I should use? I'm also not sure what values to use for the initial guess `p0`. I just chose some numbers based on the data but obviously this didn't help with the fit.

Comment: The problem is that you're fitting an exponential curve to data with high x-values, hence the fit is unstable difficult to bring to convergence. Can you transform your data (e.g. fitting the log)?

Comment: See if these paramtere values are OK:     a = 3.3878036605347397E+164, c = 4.0416321845530607E+00, tau = 4.0499652143081036E+01 giving me R-squared: 0.9858 and RMSE = 0.0015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `exp(-15000)` has to be balanced off by ridiculously large values of `a`, and the problem becomes really badly scaled, so the optimization routine fails.

Normalizing `t` so that they go from 0 to 1 helps with the scaling issue. The reasonable initial guesses then can be: 1 for tau, the smallest of y-values for c, and the difference of largest and smallest y-values for a.

```
t4_norm = (t4 - t4[0])/(t4[-1] - t4[0])   # normalized

c_0 = y4[-1]
tau_0 = 1
a_0 = (y4[0] - y4[-1])

popt4, pcov4 = curve_fit(func4, t4_norm, y4, p0=(a_0, tau_0, c_0))

a4, tau4, c4 = popt4
y4_fit = func4(t4_norm, a4, tau4, c4)
plt.plot(t4, y4, 'r.')
plt.plot(t4, y4_fit, 'b')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

After the parameters are found, they can be recalculated in terms of the original t. Indeed, the curve obtained so far is

```
y = a*exp(- (t4 - t4[0])/(t4[-1] - t4[0]) / tau) + c
```

which can be rewritten as

```
y = a*exp(t4[0]/(t4[-1] - t4[0]) / tau) * exp(-t4/(t4[-1] - t4[0]) / tau) + c
```

This means the parameters in terms of original variable are

```
a_orig = a*exp(t4[0]/(t4[-1] - t4[0]) / tau)
tau_orig = (t4[-1] - t4[0]) * tau
c_orig = c
```

Comment: With this approach can a curve fit be applied to the data with `np.exp(-t/tau)` as the fitting function? I used this form of the equation in the first example.

Comment: (1) Normalization of horizontal axis does not have anything to do with `+c` term, which is about vertical axis; (2) it would not be natural for your data. Look, it doesn't really level off at the right edge, which means there is room for the curve to go down, and we don't know how far.

Comment: Also, why not use `a_0 = y4[0]` instead of `a_0 = (y4[0] - y4[-1])`?

Comment: Because if `f(t) = a*exp(-t) + c` on the interval [0, 1], then a can be expressed as `E*(f(1)-f(0))`. So this guess has the right order of magnitude. The magnitude of `a` is related to how much y-values change, not how large they are.

Comment: Please provide an example of recalculating the parameters in terms of the original `t`. Thank you.

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: I get an overflow error from `a_orig` due to the large exponential term.

Comment: Which further confirms that the original form of equation you were trying to fit is not going to work for the data. You can still compute the coefficients by hand, they just don't fit in double precision.

Answer (score 2):

To balance the fact that you're taking the exponent of a very large number, I've added a `t0` term to your equation:

```
def func4(t, a, t0, tau, c):
    return a * np.exp(-(t-t0)/ tau) + c

# Initial guess
p0 = np.array([4.0, 15400., 6.e2, 0.], dtype=np.float64)
y4_initial = func4(t4, *p0)

# Fit
popt4, pcov4 = curve_fit(func4, t4, y4, p0=p0)
y4_fit = func4(t4, *popt4)
```

I'm getting

```
popt4 = [1.20102494e+00 1.53854910e+04 1.91852716e+01 4.07136089e+00]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you determine the initial values used for `p0`?

Comment: Mostly intuition, based on the data that you're your trying to fit. You can also plot a curve with your `p0` and tune that a bit by hand before you pass it to the fit. Of course, that is not recommended for more complex systems, where you should automatically determine your start parameters based on your data.